# Element not visible exception ( selenium C#, teamcity as service)

Tags: c#, selenium, continuous-integration, teamcity

I moved recently from protractor (client application is in angularJS) to selenium (C#) for e2e tests - had several issues with protractor stability.

For selenium everything work really fine except one important thing. I'm using TeamCity for continuous integration with agent running as service. Here comes the problem - on several tests I'm getting:

`OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.94)`

I tried to wait for element being visible or being clickable but did not help at all (got timeouts instead).

If I run tests from VS or from agent which is not registered as service everything work fine. I could technically use agent as not service but would prefer agent as service.

Is there something extra that I miss about running agent as service ? Is there some kind of protection that i could use for making my tests more stable ?

Comment: By any chance the DOM that you are trying to find is inside a table?

Comment: Unfortunately no. If that helps I'm using Angular Material as UI component framework.

Answer (score 1):

There are some known limitations on running TeamCity agent as service imposed by the operating system, see the full list [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-AgentrunningasWindowsServiceLimitations).

Comment: Does anyone found a workaround for this known issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this helps anyone later on, I've run into this issue with DevExtreme as their manipulation of the DOM is... complicated.

The best I've found to solve this problem is to tell Selenium to click at the location of the element you're concerned with, rather than attempting to click on that element directly:

`new Actions(webDriver).MoveToElement(elementInQuestion).Click().Perform()`

This moves the mouse to where the middle of the element is and performs a mouse click at that location.